# HTTPHeader in MVC or Web from

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I read a bout HTTPHeader in MVC (fundamentalbook), but i don't know what is exactly HTTPHeader ?

Could some one please explain these methods?

Comment: GET, POST, DELETE etc http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: @codingbiz, erm no, those are called HTTP verbs not HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) is a request/response protocol. The request and the response consist of 2 parts: headers and body. The headers indicate metadata about the body such as the length, the type, the compression, information about the authorization and many more. There are standard type of headers defined in the protocol but you could also use custom headers.

In ASP.NET MVC you could read request headers from the Request object and response headers from the Response object. For example:

```
Request.Headers["Content-Type"]
```

or

```
Response.Headers["Content-Type"]
```

Obviously inside the ASP.NET MVC application you can only modify the response headers. The request headers is a readonly collection as it comes from the client.

Comment: In ASP.NET *request context* usually refers to metadata which is available throughout the entire lifecycle of the execution of an HTTP request - from receiving the request up until the rendering of the markup.